# Spark select particular index from RDD and save to csv

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am selecting values from txt file using spark.sparkContext.textFile command. later i used map and filter to get the values with index.

```
f3 = fxPs.map(lambda i: (i[0] + "," + i[1] + "," + i[2] + "," + i[4]).replace("|", ",,|" + i[0] + ",").replace("|", ",,|" + i[0] + ",")).map(lambda j: j.split("|"))
```

index i[3] i don't want to select.

```
vals = f3.map(lambda e: (e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3]))
```

i can check the values using take(1)

But when i save this in csv, i get an error : 'IndexError: list index out of range'.

The index : i[3] contains multiple values, in list and i want to remove this and get only selected values from indexes in csv.

```
vals.toDF().write.format("csv").mode("append").save("/projects/")
```

thank you

Comment: Give an example and split your code f3=... in lines please

Comment: spark operates on your data as much as required, so  with `take(1)` the computation may be skipping over rows that have the actual problem. If your dataset is reasonably small, try collect() on the rdd or show() on the df. The solution may lie in eliminating any rows containing nulls.